# Pushing new Javascript objects to global array of objects with key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Within a loop, I create the following object, which is then added to a global array:

```
i++;
var objToAdd = {"code1":myvar1, "code2":myvar2, "code3":myvar3};
ary.push(objToAdd);
```

However, this adds a keyless object to the array, like so:

```
{...
{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
...}
```

And by using `i`, in the loop, I'd like to add the object keyvalue pair, like so:

```
{...
"1":{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
"2":{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
"3":{"code1":"blah", "code2":"blah", "code3":"blah"},
...}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: {} is not an array, it's an object

Comment: `[]` are 0-based arrays and `{}` are objects with string keys. Choose one: `[a, b, c]` or `{"1": a, "2": b, "3": c}`. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the linked question. Also, question edited. The `[]` and `{}` was the wrong way around, so removed from question as it doesn't apply. I need it `{{"1":{"code1":"blah"...},{},{}}` etc

Comment: If you actually boil your question down to a simpler form, it might not be a duplicate. As it stands, you've asked for us to write a bunch of code for you without explaining which part of the problem is actually blocking you from proceeding. The simplest part that *I* can see is that you don't know how to use the variable `i` to define properties `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, etc on an object. The question I closed this as a duplicate of will show you how to do this.

Comment: Also, `{}.push` is not a real thing. It definitely will *not* produce the output you claim it does. `{{a:b}}` is not valid JavaScript or JSON. Again, `{}` denotes an object literal and it contains key/value pairs, not just values. There is no such thing as adding a "keyless object to the array", as there is no *array* anywhere in your question.